# How to amalgamate 2 Clearcase Servers which each have an ADMIN Pvob

Tags: clearcase-ucm

We have a need to amalgamate 2 clearcase servers with everything then residing on one of them.

Clearcase Version 7.1.2.6 FL5 & Schema 54

Both instances have their own Admin PVOB.

How do we move and amalgamate the PVOBS or reestablish the correct links once the vobs are moved?
Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends if the servers have the same architecture or not.

The general idea is to follow the [Administration Guide (for CC 7.1.2)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_7.1.2/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_admin.doc/topics/c_relo_mv.htm) describing how to move VOB (and PVob) from one server to another.

The different scenario are [described here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_7.1.2/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_admin.doc/topics/c_mvvob.htm).

Comment: Hi Thanks, The Moving of a PVOB first then component VOBS i'm happy about. Therefore as both instances will have admin PVOB once we migrate everything to the one server can we retain the 2 ADMIN PVOBS  with their own set of linked PVOBS? Or would we have to combine the both admin PVOBS into a single one. Unfortunately we are looking at 2 possible scenarios one where both VOB servers are AIX and the other we are going from AIX to Windows.

Comment: @DBeange I always prefered to move *all* PVob first, instead of Admin PVob, then children PVob. I never had to merge 2 PVob though.

Comment: Hi Thanks, Have dug further on this and the situation is less clear so will post a fresh question as the set up seems a bit Siamese.